# How to disable the extension menu icon on Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, browser-addons, extension, addons

IS there a way to disable it or make it unsuable ? I really need to take it off. IS there a way to completely hide the toolbar ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/REMd3.png I talk about the jigsaw icon. Can't you see ? It's on the picture c'mon. I don't want it only in incognito mode + it doesn't even work

Comment: The jigsaw icon

Comment: I really searched everywhere but I didn't founnd the way

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please Help. It doesn't answer my question AT ALL.